# Pixel Density (Bucket) Relative to Which Devices?

Tags: android

I've had a group of developers working on an app that delivers HTML-based page content, built in a CSS & Tables construct. There is a separate database of content for all the different pixel density specs: hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, mdpi, lmdpi, etc. I assumed that devices falling into a certain size category would pull from one of these databases. In order to verify which database a device was pulling from while I'm working on different ones, I tagged the content of each database with an identifier specific to its pixel density.

Today I began applying content specs to the Nexus 7 database, which is XXHDPI. I got the HTML display to a point I called near-perfect. Then I turned my attention to the Samsung Galaxy S4 (I started with these two devices because I have them in hand). What I discovered right away, though, is that the Samsung Galaxy S4 is also pulling from the XXHDPI database, the same as the Nexus 7. But none of the specs I've imposed on the XXHDPI data for the Nexus 7 are going to work for the Galaxy S4.

Is this correct, that the S4 and the Nexus 7—one a tablet, the other a phone—should both be pulling from the XXHDPI database? At this WikiPedia link, the Samsung Galaxy S4 is shown as XHDPI. Is there an "official" definitive listing of devices and their pixel buckets?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Samsung

Thanks for any help.

Cayce